# Show inequality with the minimum of a convex function

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, convex-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a convex map.
We define for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$
$$ g_x(y) = f(y) + \frac{1}{2} \lVert x-y \rVert^2 .$$
Using convexity of $g_x$ I already showed that $g_x$ admit a minimum at some point which we will call $p_x$.
I want to show that this point $p_x$ is characterised by the following inequality
$$ \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n, f(y) - f(p_x) - \langle x - p_x, y - p_x \rangle \geq 0 .$$
I tried to use that $g_x(y) - g_x(p_x) \geq 0$ but I don't arrive to an end.

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be $f(y)-f(p_x)+\langle x-p_x, y-p_x\rangle\geq 0$? I say this because if you assume $f$ is smooth so that the $\min$ for $g_x$ is attained at  $p_x$ satisfying $\nabla f(p_x)= p_x-x$ and then using the convexity of $f$ we get (I think, I may have made a mistake) the inequality with the plus instead of minus sign.